# I have a problem with a Google Cloud Platform WordPress deployment pointing to the wrong ip address

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

I was using a GCP free trial that ended. I then upgraded and had to Started the VM instance so I could get back the WordPress site I was trialing.  A new ip address has been given. The home page shows but all other pages and the wp-admin point to the old ip address.  How do I get the ip address to be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You only need to do this in most cases when migrating a website to a new Wordpress application or an existing Wordpress site from one host to another.

Install Wordpress and update the URL Path using the artcile - http://helpcenter.infoquest.com/knowledgebase/articles/606702-changing-the-wordpress-url-path - now you can update the IP address.

Within the customer control panel via https://cp.infoquest.com > Click the More Services Tab > Click Databases > Click the database name > Click the link to Browse Database Manager. This will launch phpmyadmin.

Once within phpmyadmin, on the left click the database name > Click wp_options. You will need to change 2 fields, siteurl & home, from the domain name to the new exclusive IP address. Click the pencil icon "Edit" to change the fields. Example:

old siteurl: http://domainname.com
old home: http://domainname.com

new siteurl: http://65.61.x.x
new home: http://65.61.x.x

You can find your exclusive IP address within the customer control panel via https://cp.infoquest.com > Hosted Domains > Click the domain name in question > Click the Web Tab > Click Edit > Change the IP address Type from shared to exclusive.

I would recommend to make Wordpress Site static

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to an answer to someone elses similar question in 2013 by The Humble Rat I have solved the problem.

You need to make a change to your database. In the database table wp_options (or whatever your database prefix is), you need to change two lines. 
One should be option_id 1, option_name siteurl. Change the option_value from the old url to the new url.
Similarly there should also be option_id 36, option_name home. Change the option_value also from the old url to the new url.